# asp.net mvc avoid if - Else logic for controls in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have next code in my View:

```
   @if (Model is Manager)
        {
           //render manager button
        }
        else if (Model is Developer)
        {
            //render Developer button
        }
        else if (Model is UX)
        {
            //render UX button
        }
```

This works, but I'm looking best way to do it.
Any idea?

Comment: This way is fine, that is what Razor was designed for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use extension method to implement control logic for different entities.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString userButton(this HtmlHelper html, Manager user)
    {
        string buttonForManager = //...
        return new MvcHtmlString(buttonForManager);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString userButton(this HtmlHelper html, Developer user)
    {
         string buttonForDeveloper = //...
        return new MvcHtmlString(buttonForDeveloper);
    }
```

Use in View:

```
@Html.userButton(Model)
```